# Structuring Unstructured Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to structure an unstructured data set.

Data appears in the following 5 columns:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSHZ0.png)

Descriptors tells you how many cells to the right will be filled this number can range from 2-4 (as shown or to 20/30)

I want to be able to search for completion and incomplete and count the frequency this happens, then completion complete.

I am welcome to any suggestions including VBA. Completion is the simplest category that is used

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7IaY.png)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do. Your title states you are trying to *structure data*, but it appears you only want to *count* values. Which is it, or is there more to the story?

Comment: In your example, which column holds incomplete or complete? Why are some rows filtered - does this matter? Where are these descriptors?

Comment: To Wayne G. Dunn & Nick.McDermaid comments from the data dump (I have shown the first 100 rows, from each dataset the number of rows change change depending how many categories occur in game) there is a number of things I want to do to the data set. Starting with  a formula/method that can pull all this information into an standardised table, so that I can can run produce reports, Stat test, create charts etc. 

As you can see with more rows, although the same words/values keep reappearing within descriptors the row/column they don’t appear in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of oversimplifying your task, I don't think you even need VBA.  I think a formula will work.  In this case the `SUMIF` formula can count the number of instances of Complete or Incomplete.

If you add columns K and L with the following formulas respectively:

```
=COUNTIF(G2:J2,"=Incomplete")
=COUNTIF(G2:J2,"=Complete")
```

It will count the number of occurrences.  Then all you need to do is sum up those columns.

Here is what it would look like:

[image]

You don't need to do this, but if you convert your range to a table, it will really help with scaling the data and formula applications.

Comment: To @Hambone, I have thought about COUNTIF, INDEX MATCH, VLOOKUP but am unable to get them to search and “category” and then that full row, which would seem the simplest method of solving this.

Comment: I have added the first 100 rows, from each dataset to show you what I mean.

Comment: Can you, at least for sample purposes, give the example with your desired output?  I'm still nto 100% sure what the result needs to look like.  It sounds quite doable.  It also sounds like you need a database to load this into, but that's probably another topic.

Comment: I have added the database I would want the date to go into. Then I can then use the data for charts etc.

Comment: That helps...  Yes, you do have something that cannot be done with just formulas and standard Excel.  And you want the times (from columns A/B) to go into those cells in the middle?

Comment: A/B Columns times would be collected and then added to there own area on the data sheet. I have a formula to convert them to the correct time format. This times would then be used with the descriptions and categories